# Linear Algebra - Union of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble answering the following question:

If $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is the union of $V$ and $W$ necessarily a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Given $V$ and $W$ are subspaces, the zero vector must be present, but I have a hard time understanding how to "proof" closed under multiplication and addition.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "*vector subspace*" instead of "*subset*"? The answer is trivially "Yes" for subsets.

Comment: The answer is **no** for subspaces. Consider the X-Axis and the Y-Axis as subspaces of the plane. Their Union isn't. The sum sum of the standard vectors *i* and *j* is *i + j* which isn't part of either, so closure is violated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $n=2$.

Let $V= \{ (t,0): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $W= \{ (0,w): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$(1,0) \in V \cup W$ and $(0,1) \in V \cup W$

what about the sum?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you meant “subspaces” and not “subsets”. The answer is negative. Take $n=2$, $V=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $W=\{(0,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then $(1,0),(0,1)\in V\cup W$, but $(1,0)+(0,1)\notin V\cup W$.

Actually, the union of two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace if and only if one of them contains the other one.